# csrf token: CSRF attack detected. for backend in production only

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I added the security: true flag to my settings for the backend and was able to log in just fine in my dev env, but not having any luck in production. I keep getting the above error. Any ideas or directions you could point me in?

Comment: Can you show us how you render the form?

Comment: it's via the Guard plugin, so it's all automatic. The token is getting included in the form.

Comment: That got me thinking though, I have  no_script_name set to true, I bet it's trying to submit the form to the front end. I'll run a test and report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because in my production env I have no_script_name set to true and the login request was getting forward to the front end app which didn't recognize the token. I set up a subdomain with `DirectoryIndex backend.php` set in the vhost. Problem solved.